# Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' reported error: Authentication requires secure connection

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I'm running 2 MySQL 8.0.36 servers on a Windows server using the same configuration except the data and temp directories, as well as the TCP ports and the socket names. The SSL is disabled on both servers.

When I try to connect with the MySQL8's client from the command line I'm able to connect to one of the servers, but for the other it fails with the error in the title.

`have_ssl` is disabled on a session and global level on both servers, `authentication_policy` is set to `*,,` on both servers as reported via `SHOW (GLOBAL) VARIABLES ...`, `default_authentication_plugin` is set to `caching_sha2_password` on both servers. The `mysql.user.plugin` is set to `caching_sha2_password` for the particular user on both instances.

The only difference between the servers is that the working one was migrated from 5.7 while the failing one was freshly initialized using the MySQL8 tools.

How to solve this inconsistency ?